# Define newvarlist for imported variables when using the merge command in Stata

Tags: merge, local, stata

I'm importing several variables from a .dta file into my current database using `merge`:

```
merge 1:1 id using "data.dta", keepusing(a1 b2 c3 d4)
```

(variable names not real). I want to define a local group like this:

```
local VARLIST a1 b2 c3 d4
```

However, because the variables' name might change over time I want to automatize the process by creating a list containing the imported variables. `merge` does not have a `r(varlist)` output so I cannot do this directly. Moreover, I already have variables in my database so using `ds, local newlistname r(varlist)` is not enough. I have Stata 12.

Comment: I don't think I understand. You know the variables you will use for the `keepusing()` option, but you can't put them in a local? Why is that? Maybe you want to explain why you want to do this so better advice can be given.

Comment: Variables imported change depending on what I need so they are not fixed. That is why I want to define a new list with them in an automatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
 /* Make some fake data */
 sysuse auto, clear
 save auto.dta, replace
 rename (price-foreign) xxx_=

 /* Key Part */
 unab oldvarnames: _all
 merge 1:1 make using auto.dta, keepusing(price mpg) nogen 
 unab newvarnames: _all
 local added:list newvarnames - oldvarnames
 di "`added'"
```

Essentially, you are subtracting the pre-merge variable names from the post-merge variable names to find what was added.

Since you are using Stata 12, you might bump up against the string length limits, so caveat legulus.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Didn't know that you could operate over lists. New world opens for me, thanks. Still, for this particular case it would be much easy if merge produces a `r(varlist)` as other commands do.

Comment: @luchonacho More on lists [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/pmacrolists.pdf) for version 13.